# Cannot set background-image to body

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Google Chrome Extension but before I actually put it together, I'm trying to get this function working properly.

The purpose of the extension is when the opened page is an image file, you click the extension button and it tiles the image.

The function I have is only 3 lines but doesn't work at the 3rd line for some reason.

```
function tileImage() {
    var img = $('img').prop('src');
    $('img').remove();
    $('body').css('background', 'url(' + img + ')');
}
```

I have injected jQuery into the page so that's not the problem. It's the third line, setting the background. It works fine when I set something like the margin but for some reason not this.

Can someone please explain to me why this doesn't work and suggest a possible fix.

Thanks.

Comment: When you `console.log(img)` are you seeing an image URL or *undefined*?

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/d5E5W/ Maybe show us your HTML.

Comment: @Popnoodles Yes it works in jsfiddle but open up the image in a new tab and try to achieve this with the javascript console.

Comment: Open the image in a new tab? There is no `$('img')` if you do that. It's just image data. That's your problem. Open an HTML page with an `<img>` inside it. That's your solution. Wait... how did you insert jQuery?

Comment: Popnoodles is correct, you can inject you're code and see a body tag within firebug, doesn't mean it's an html page.

Comment: @Popnoodles Open an image in a new tab. Inpect it. You'll see it's a `img` element inside a `body` element. And you can inject jQuery easily.

Comment: I can see what you can see, but that's your inspector doing that; It's not what's really on the page. Otherwise how is that `<img>` loading when its src is an HTML page with an `<img>` tag, and that img is another HTML page with an `<img>` tag etc etc... The browser is rendering image data.

Comment: @Popnoodles At the time I thought it would work. Editing the actual HTML the page creates I can get it to tile... I'll have to find another way around this then I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
function tileImage() {
    var img = $('img').prop('src');
    // OR $('img').attr('src');
    $('img').remove();
    $('body').css({'background': 'url(' + img + ') no-repeat'});
}
```

Here worked perfectly! Or maybe i don't understood what you wanted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
<script>
    function tileImage() {
        var img = $('img').prop('src');
        $('img').remove();
        $('body').css({'background': 'url(' + img + ') no-repeat'});
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src='http://stacktoheap.com/images/stackoverflow.png'/>
<button onclick='tileImage();'>Click</button>
<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

You want open the image in a new tab ?

Comment: I've understood that what I thought was possible actually isn't. See here for a revised question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432372/create-new-page-chrome-extension

Answer (score -2):

First of all, src is not a propertie but an attributes

```
<input type="text" required disabled />

$('input').attr('type')
$('input').attr('type', 'number');
$('input').prop('required')
$('input').prop('required', true)
```

You're code is find, it should change your background, try adding double quote to you're source, and change just the property 'background-image'

Comment: `prop()` gets attributes too. This does not try to answer the question.

Comment: yes it does, doesn't mean it is correct and because the rest of the code is correct, this is the only thing I see, you should post a jsfiddle, Edit : can you wait before voting down?*

Comment: `$('img').prop('src');` and `$('img').attr('src');` get the EXACT same thing. Test it.

Comment: Spedwards : id doesnt do the same thing, check the jquery code to see by yourself. property and attribute should NOT be use the same way, read jquery documentation. I didn't provide a solution, he didn't provide a bug, wait for the jsfiddle

Comment: If the answer is wrong, you downvote it. You don't flag it unless it is not an answer at all. Wrong answers are still answers.